# Error when copying vector bool to CUDA memory

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, nvidia

I encountered a compilation error where copying a bool vector to cuda memory will fail

```
bool *gpu; 

cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&gpu), 100);

std::vector<bool> cpu(100);

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  cpu[i]=true;
}

cudaMemcpy(gpu, cpu.data(), 100*sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

It returns

```
error: invalid use of void expression cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

but the same code with a float vector will compile.

```
float *gpu; 

cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&gpu), 100);

std::vector<float> cpu(100);

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  cpu[i]=i;
}

cudaMemcpy(gpu, cpu.data(), 100*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: [`vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is special, and not in a good way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a mistake from C++98 that we cannot get rid of (at least in terms of occupying the name). The standard recommends that it keeps the storage as *a space-optimized representation of bits* and that's what most implementations do.

You can work around this by using `vector<uint8_t>` instead.

Comment: After a quick test it seems to be working properly. Also it should be uint8_t instead of uin8_t.